# iOS custom status bar that only replaces carrier icon

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, statusbar, uiapplication

I'm creating a zombie preparedness app for iOS and I thought it would be cool to have an "Apocalypse mode" which is similar to Airplane mode in that it replaces the status bar carrier icon with a little airplane except possibly with a little mushroom cloud or something instead?

Apocalypse mode would just be a boolean flag in my app the disables all data connection required features (only within the app, not using any private APIs or anything...).  If possible, I would still like to have the clock, battery life, Bluetooth icons and whatever else that pops up onto the status bar during normal operation.

I'm looking at the [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) library to implement this feature.  Related ([Stackoverflow post here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone).  I know there is a possibility my app could get rejected for style because of this, but my thought is that I don't want to stray to far from the norm and cross my fingers Apple doesn't jump on me for it.

My question is

1. How can I copy over the clock and battery life icons?  Do I need to hook into an event or is there a UI element I can add.
2. Am I going about this the right way?  Would it be better to just make a transparent overlay on top of the normal status bar with a mushroom cloud that overlays the carrier icon instead of replacing the status bar entirely?  I'm worried about variable length carrier icons...

Of course option 3 is I just forget that idea entirely and make some sort of different background or something for this mode, but that seems lame :P

Comment: I have a feeling your app may not be approved if you are going to just "disable" the users' data connections.

Comment: It's only effective within my app.  My app provides services the work both offline and online.  I would like to disable the online services I provide in my app and use a nifty little icon to denote the mode (only within the app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go with something similar a while ago. I created a status bar overlay that accepted touch events, but didn't block the status bar from receiving touches, which is crucial for app store acceptance. 
You can check out [my question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448613/passing-touch-events-to-ios-status-bar), however keep in mind it might not be actual anymore, it worked great in iOS4, but never tested it on 5. Worth a try though.

As for the overlay itself, I suggest covering everything up to the clock, and leaving the rest transparent, it should do the job.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand.  You made a transparent view that overlayed your app status bar?  What was the purpose of doing that in your app, did you have some sort of visual overlay?  May I ask what your app was?  As for doing an overlay I hadn't thought of the touch aspect but I can see that is important!

Comment: The relevant sample code is in the question I linked. I don't have anything more as we aren't doing anything like that anymore. The idea back then was a non-modal notification management interface, similar to what iOS5 and Android are doing. Since iOS5 it isn't needed anymore as notifications aren't modal anymore. I didn't need any visuals, just a full length transparent view on top of the status bar that intercepted touches, and just as importantly, passed them on.

Comment: After spending a whole morning on this I'm pretty sure this is the way to go combined with creating the view like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833724/adding-view-on-statusbar-in-iphone.  But for the life of me I can't get the view to actually show up!  Maybe its prevented in iOS 5?  Anyway I'll give you the solution and post back later if I get it all working smoothly.