# Accessing the Status Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I'd like to receive touches from the status bar anywhere, any view, from the app. Well actually only specific views, like home screens and root view controllers say from a view of a tab view controller.

**So my goal is to:** hold down the status bar to dismiss the current view, like a back button.

The reason why I'm using this approach as a back button is because the app I am making is a utility, like fully functional apps within one app. Therefore I do not want to use up space on the navbar item to display a back button.

Other fissures would be nice, like swipe left/right or double tap, but mostly holding down. I've seen alternatives like using a `UIScrollView` and use the `- scrollsToTop` method. Hmm not what I am looking for.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar
OR Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448613/passing-touch-events-to-ios-status-bar

Comment: Fantastic, I'll have to try it out. I love how the good answer is not the "correct" answer :)

Comment: First try and let me know man

Comment: first one worked out great :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

When you tap the top area, which has 44 height, the event would be triggered.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBack:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}



- (void)navigationBack:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    CGPoint p = [tapGesture locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44), p)) {
        NSLog(@"this where you put you navigation back event");
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i paste this implementation?

Comment: I pasted this in the view controller and it appears to only work in the view, which is below the status bar vs part of it. thank you tho :)